# AEM Servlet RuntimeNodeTraversalException

Tags: servlets, aem

I am trying to learn how to use AEM and I made a simple AEM servlet to test it.

```
@SlingServlet(Path ={"/bin/Exp/test01"}, method={"Get"})
public class TestServlet extends SlingSafeMethodsServlet {

  @Override
  protected void doGet(@NotNull SlingHttpServletRequest request, @NotNull SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.getWriter().write("Hello World");
```

This servlet works fine and returns "Hello World" when I call it using POSTMAN. But after I change the code to this:

```
@SlingServlet(Path ={"/bin/Exp/test01"}, method={"Get"})
public class TestServlet extends SlingSafeMethodsServlet {

  @Override
  protected void doGet(@NotNull SlingHttpServletRequest request, @NotNull SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String Data = request.getParameter("ExpData");
    response.getWriter().write(Data);
```

and call this API with POSTMAN and past ExpData value in, POSTMAN returns nothing and the connection code is "404 Not Found". I checked the AEM log and it shows "org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.RuntimeNodeTraversalException: The query read or traversed more than 100000 nodes. To avoid affecting other tasks, processing was stopped"

I tried to increase the "In memory read limit" in AEM Configuration Manager but still doesn't work. I googled this issue but can't find any useful solutions. Please give me some advises. Thank you

Comment: If there is no query to the CRX within the servlet, the error message is not related with the 404. The SlingServlet annotation is deprecated. Please check out the sling [documentation](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/servlets.html#registering-a-servlet-using-java-annotations).

Answer (score -1):

Problem solved, I changed the code like this :

```
@Component(service=Servlet.class)
@SlingServletPaths("/bin/test01")
public class TestServlet exteds SlingAllMethodsServlet {
  @Override
  protected void doGet(@NotNull SlingHttpServletRequest request, @NotNull SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String Data = request.getParameter("ExpData");
    response.getWriter().write(Data);
  }
}
```

And send a POST request with the parameter, the servlet can received the data.